# Chrome extension JavaScript camera doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am creating chrome extension which shows the camera on current page when I click on the extension icon. The camera code separately in index html works well, but when I am trying to use it in chrome extension it shows me error: "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at  and .", it seems that my camera light is switched on but there is not camera anywhere, can someone help me please?

Code in **content.js**

```
    let html = `
            <div id="container">
       <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
       </div>
         `;

    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function(err0r) {
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
    function stop(e) {
      var stream = video.srcObject;
      var tracks = stream.getTracks();

      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        var track = tracks[i];
        track.stop();
      }

      video.srcObject = null;
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: `if (ShowCamera === "true")`, this might be your problem, you're comparing a boolean value to a string which will always come out as `false`, try doing `if(ShowCamera)` instead.

Comment: It "shows an error" -- it might make sense to include that error. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: i've already corrected it

Comment: @SalomeSulaberidze Then add what you did as an answer to the question please.